Deriving the expression for non-adiabatic coupling elements
I am trying to understand the derivation for the non-adiabatic coupling (NAC) elements as presented in Conical Intersections Electronic Structure, Dynamics and Spectroscopy by Wolfgang Domcke and Horst Koppel. Where it is shown that the NAC can be expressed as $$\bf{\Lambda}\mathrm{_{ji} = \delta_{ji}T_n-\langle j(\bf{R})|\mathrm{T_n}|i(\bf{R})\rangle}$$
Where $R$ are the collective nuclear coordinates. Obviously the above elements are operators in $R$ - space and $T_n$ being the nuclear kinetic energy operator. Now the author states that if we take $$T_n = -\frac{1}{2M}\nabla^2$$ where the gradient $\nabla$ vector acts on the nuclear space. The expression for $\Lambda_{ij}$ becomes $$\Lambda_{ji}=\frac{1}{2M}[2\textbf{F}_{ji}(R)\cdot\nabla+G_{ji}]$$ where $$\textbf{F}_{ji}=\langle j(R) | \nabla i(R)\rangle$$ and  $$G_{ji}=\langle j(R) | \nabla^2 i(R)\rangle$$ However, I do not reach the same expression on plugging in the expression for $T_n$ into the expression for $\Lambda_{ji}$. Instead simply plugging it in results in the expression $$\Lambda_{ji}=-\frac{\delta_{ji}}{2M}\nabla^2+\frac{\langle j(R) | \nabla^2 i(R)\rangle}{2M}$$ The rightmost term seems to be same as the $G_{ji}$ as defined by the author. But I have no idea how to manipulate the first term into the $\textbf{F}_{ji}$ term that the author claims would appear.
